# how to save data to variable from data array

Tags: php, laravel

I get this data array from form and I need to save this array data to five different variables, so how I do,
this is filled with images data

```
 +files: Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\FileBag {#61 ▼
    #parameters: array:1 [▼
      "img" => array:5 [▼
        0 => Symfony\.... {#42 ▶}
        1 => Symfony\....{#43 ▶}
        2 => Symfony\....{#44 ▶}
        3 => Symfony\.... {#45 ▶}
        4 => Symfony\....{#46 ▶}
      ]
    ]
```

I need to add data to these variables

```
$img1 = 0
$img2 = 1
$img3 = 2
$img4 = 3
$img5 = 4
```

Comment: I think you need to learn how to use arrays or the corresponding class methods rather than extracting to variables.  Variables called `img1`, 2... is usually indication that arrays should be used.

Comment: im new to coding

Answer (score 1):

You can use `${$variable_name}` syntactic sugar from php to assign or get variable from using string as variable name

```
$img0 = null; $img1 = null; $img2 = null; $img3 = null; $img4 = null; $img5 = null; 

foreach($files['img'] as $key => $file){
    $varname = 'img' . $key; //img1 , img2 , img3 ...

    ${$varname} = $key; // $img1 = 0, $img1 = 1, $img3 = 1;
}
```

I think this code will be solution for you

Answer (score 0):

Maybe using 'list ()' you can achieve what you want.

[PHP: Returning values #Example2](https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.returning-values.php)

```
list($img1, $img2, $img3, $img4, $img5) = array_values($files['img']);

// $img1 the first image
// $img2 the second image
// etc
```